# How to find JSON data at specific index

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to show only the country name like India,Srilanka etc.

```
{"result":1,"countries":[
    {"country_id":"1","country_name":"Afghanistan"},
    {"country_id":"2","country_name":"Albania"},
    {"country_id":"3","country_name":"Algeria"},
    {"country_id":"4","country_name":"American Samoa"},
    {"country_id":"5","country_name":"Andorra"},
    {"country_id":"6","country_name":"Angola"},
    {"country_id":"7","country_name":"Anguilla"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: where "here" ? What do you want exactly?

Comment: Hi @Prashant - do you have any attempts to share with us? As it currently stands, it just appears that you are asking us to perform this task for you. You are not asking any questions here - just listing requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I have created JSON object same as yours:

```
var text = '{"result":1,"countries":[' +
'{"country_id":"1","country_name":"Afghanistan"},' +
'{"country_id":"2","country_name":"Albania"},' +
'{"country_id":"3","country_name":"Algeria"}'+
']}';

var obj = JSON.parse(text);
```

you can loop through JSON object and get each property value as below:

```
for(i = 0; i < obj.countries.length ; i++) 
{
    console.log(obj.countries[i].country_name);
}
```

Hope This Will Help!

Answer (score 0):

why no iterate the objects and pull that data into a separate array? for example:

```
[[{"country_id":"1","country_name":"Afghanistan"},{"country_id":"2","country_name":"Albania"},{"country_id":"3","country_name":"Algeria"},{"country_id":"4","country_name":"American Samoa"},{"country_id":"5","country_name":"Andorra"},{"country_id":"6","country_name":"Angola"},{"country_id":"7","country_name":"Anguilla"}]]
.forEach(function(element) {
    console.log(element.country_name);
});
```

Comment: While your post does answer the question (and it is clear that you are just trying to help :P ), it is generally discouraged to provide answers to posts that clearly did not put much effort into researching the problem. For example, you are assuming that the OP knows how to extract the `countries` array. Observing the attempts made by the OP to solve their issue is a great way to know how to approach helping them. In this case, we don't have any information to work with.

Comment: Just to clarify - I am not trying to discourage you (or anyone else) from trying to help people out - not at all! My comment is more aimed at educating the question askers to provide more context and effort when asking the community for assistance.

Comment: @Lix I agree and will take into consideration next time